# Loop terminating prematurely for multiple queries

Tags: c++, c++11, pattern-matching

For [this](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/827/C) problem I need to to do multiple queries so I used a for loop for it

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int>ans; //vector to store the ans
    string s,e; //real dna and virus dna 
    cin>>s;
    int q,start,match=0; // no. of queries, starting value of the query, var to store matching occurence
    unsigned int step=0; //var to keep count of virus dna iteration

    cin>>q;
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){//loop to iterate q times 
        cin>>start;
        int l,r,x,c; 
    if(start==2){ // for 2nd type query
            cin>>l>>r>>e;

        for(int i=l-1;i<=r-1;i++){
            if(s[i]==e[step]){
                match+=1;   
            }
            step+=1;
            if(step== e.length()){
                step=0;        //starting again from start of virus
            }
        }   
        }
ans.push_back(match);
match=0;   //reintializing value for next query


    if(start==1){ //for 1st type query
        cin>>x>>c;
        s[x-1]=c; //replacing char at x-1 with c
    }


}


for(int j=0;j<ans.size();j++){ //loop for ans output
    cout<<ans[j]<<endl;
}

    return 0;
}
```

but it terminates before it should for ex: for this input,

```
ATGCATGC
4  
2 1 8 ATGC  
2 2 6 TTT  
1 4 T 
2 2 6 TA
```

It would stop at 5th line and print 8 ,2 ,0, 0 whereas it should be 8, 2, 4. If I do individual queries without loop things work fine but any kind of loop doesn't work. Pls help. Also any suggestion for solving this kind of problems more efficiently  will be very helpful to me.

Comment: `I used a for loop for it but it terminates before it should` - please, provide the code

Comment: Provided..sorry for the delay

Comment: *"Also any suggestion for solving this kind of problems more efficiently will be very helpful to me."* - use Python or some easier language.  C++ is a waste of time for this.

Comment: Please, could you do a better indentation?

Comment: At least two points in your code: are you sure you shouldn't clear (or update) `step` after entering new `e` value? The second one: you should move `ans.push_back(match);` into the first `if` body, because you have to give answer only for the second type of query.

Comment: yes the 2nd point is very helpful thanks but could you explain 1st point? Where exactly should I change 'step'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bigger problem in your code is that the variable `c` is defined as `int`

```
int l,r,x,c;
```

when receive chars and not integers (`T`, in your example) so should be defined as `char`

```
int l,r,x; 
char c;
```

If `c` is `int`, when you send `4 T` to

```
cin>>x>>c;
```

`x` receive 4, `c` doesn't receive `T` (`T` isn't a valid `int`) so start the next iteration of the external cycle, is called

```
cin>>start;
```

when `T` remain in the buffer; `start` is integer so there is the same problem and the program end.

And, as pointed by soon, `ans.push_back()` should be inside the first if. Now a value (zero) is added also with rows starting with `1`.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.I fixed as you said but still the loop terminates after 5th line.

Comment: @stealth225 - can you transcribe your modified code?

Comment: moved ans.push_back() in the first if block after the 2nd for loop and changed int c to char c.

Comment: @stealth225 - with `char c` and `push_back()` inside the if, I can insert all input rows and I get three rows (`8`, `2` and `0`) of output. The only problem I see is that the last value should `4`, not `0`.

Comment: and I can't even insert the last row

Comment: @stealth - have you recompiled your code after the modifications?

Comment: @stealth225 - sorry but if you don't transcribe the full and exact code your compiling, I don't know how to help you

Comment: found that I wasn't doing cin>>c;..yes the loop works now but wrong answer at the end..I guess that is a different issue. I am ticking your ans since it solves the problem with loop which was the topic.